# Doubts about EF Core 2.1 Relations

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on Entity Framework Core Code First approach and ASP.Net Core 2.1 making 3 tables:

1. Person class

```
public class Person
{
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public PeopleProfessions PeopleProfessions { get; set; }
}
```

2. Professions' class

```
public class Profession
{
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public PeopleProfessions PeopleProfessions { get; set; }
}
```

3. peopleprofessions' class

```
public class peopleprofessions
{
        [ForeignKey("PersonId ")]
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProfessionId")]
        public string ProfessionId{ get; set; }
        public ICollection<Profession> Professions { get; set; }
}
```

On my Context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(builder);

     builder.Entity<peopleprofessions>().HasKey(up => new { up.PersonId, up.ProfessionId });
}
```

Bearing this in mind:

- People can have multiple professions.
- The professions table is only for reading stored data like "Accountant".

I have doubts about how I can make table 3 only contain the foreigners and that it can meet the needs that I just mentioned.

I have tried to make the relationship appropriately but I also noticed that in tables 1 and 2 it requests both Id of the table people's professions.

I don't know if I am lost or if I am looking wrong or if there is an alternative to that situation. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: can you include your model configuration code?

Comment: I just updated the post with the classes I have

Comment: What is you actual question ?

Comment: I do not understand very well how to implement it properly based on the two points mentioned and Entity framework Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the use of Collections on the navigation items a bit backwards. For your primary entities (Person and Profession), they should have collections, since it's one-to-many.  But for the PeopleProfessions, each record is a single link to a specific entity, so no collection there just a direct object reference.

```
public class Person
{
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PeopleProfessions> PeopleProfessions { get; set; }
}

public class Profession
{
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public ICollection<PeopleProfessions> PeopleProfessions { get; set; }
}

public class PeopleProfessions
{
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }

        public string ProfessionId { get; set; }
        public Profession Profession { get; set; }
}
```

You can, but don't need to specify a ForeignKey attribute because you are following EFs naming conventions(it will figure it out for you). Your OnModelCreating looks correct for the composite key.

You may want to consider removing the plural from PeopleProfessions (just call the class PeopleProfession) since one instance represents a single People-Profession relationship.  I typically do this and but the navigation name in the entities remains plural, since it can represent more than one, i.e.

```
public ICollection<PeopleProfession> PeopleProfessions { get; set; }
```

Comment: Leave the OnModelCreating code there.  Your code looks correct for the composite key.

Comment: Thanks for the help, do you know where I can learn better about these things? since I feel something bad on relationships

Comment: This is a good starting point:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: Really, thank you so much. I just got one more question: Can I use the Key Attribute in the class instead of the Fluent API?

Comment: You can use the "Key" attribute on both Ids in the PeopleProfessions class if you want.  Personally (and I think MS has shifted this way), I prefer to use FluentApi, since it keeps your entity classes clean and you can put your DB related config in its own class.  If you go to the URL I referenced and search for the "Many-to-many" section, you will see that MS's example also uses FluentAPI.